# CASE WHEN based on GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I am working on a migration from a legacy system to a new standard system. The legacy system accept 0 as quantity and a positive amount, whereas the new system requires a negative or positive qty.

To achieve this I have tried to group the 0-quantity lines with the ones with a qty.

For example:

```sql
Select
  Refnr
  ,CASE WHEN QTY=0 AND Code='000' THEN '112'
     ELSE CODE END AS CODE
  ,Qty
  ,Amount
FROM TABLE
```

However, my problem is that sometimes the the code should be changed to something else and that is based on the other data in the same refnr. So if the same refnr has both code 000 and 345 then 000 should be changed to 345, whereas in the first case it should be changed to 112.

How can I fetch this information?

The table looks like this

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDtBr.png)

and I want the result (a view) to look like this

[EXPECTED VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgYlI.png)

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results as *consumable text*, not [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different ways.)

Answer (score 0):

We use `lead()` to change the `code` from `0` to the one after it and then we could use `group by()` to get the desired results.

```
select   refrn  
        ,code
        ,sum(qty)    as qty
        ,sum(amount) as amount
from    (
select   refrn
        ,case code when 0 then lead(code) over(partition by refrn order by code) else code end as code
        ,qty
        ,amount
from     t 
         ) t 
group by refrn, code
order by refrn
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oq3GI5nr)

Comment: Thanks, I will make a try. I do have a small issue though. I have far more codes than in my example. Most of them should not be affected. But this could be a help on the way!

Comment: It will only affect the 000 ones and the next ones. All the rest will stay the same.